# How do you add Gtk::Notebook tabs at runtime from Glade definitions?

Tags: c++, tabs, gtkmm, glade

I am creating a new GTK app (using gtkmm) and the main interface is tabbed, a bit like a web browser.

I want to create a new tab for each document the user opens, with the content of each tab being defined by Glade.  I'm new to gtkmm, so I am not sure how to do this.

If I design my tab in Glade as a self-contained window, when I call `Gtk::Builder::get_widget()` it returns a pointer to the `Gtk::Window`, but I can't pass this to `Gtk::Notebook::append_page()` because that function requires a reference and I only have a pointer.  I don't want to dereference the pointer, because I believe each call to `get_widget()` returns the same pointer - so if I want to add five pages the same, I need to somehow clone the UI structure before adding it to the `Gtk::Notebook` - otherwise changing a UI element on one tab will cause it to change on the other four tabs too as they are all pointing to the same UI widgets.

What is the best way to take a window designed in Glade and dynamically add it multiple times to a `Gtk::Notebook`?

---

**EDIT:**

Putting each tab's definitions into a separate `*.glade` file does allow me to load multiple instances so that part is all good.

However I still can't add the loaded structure to the `Gtk::Notebook`:

- If I tell `Gtk::Builder::get_widget()` to retrieve the root `Gtk::Window` from the `.glade` file and add that as the new tab, it won't compile because I have to pass a `Gtk::Widget` to `append_page()` and it won't accept a `Gtk::Window` parameter instead.
- If I tell it to pick the top-most widget instead, then I get a bunch of runtime errors:

  ```
  Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
  gtkcontainer.c:858: container class `gtkmm__GtkWindow' has no child property named `tab-expand'
  gtkcontainer.c:858: container class `gtkmm__GtkWindow' has no child property named `tab-fill'
  gtkcontainer.c:858: container class `gtkmm__GtkWindow' has no child property named `tab-label'
  gtkcontainer.c:858: container class `gtkmm__GtkWindow' has no child property named `menu-label'
  gtkcontainer.c:858: container class `gtkmm__GtkWindow' has no child property named `position'
  Gtk:ERROR:gtkcontainer.c:3541:gtk_container_propagate_draw: assertion failed: (gtk_widget_get_parent (child) == GTK_WIDGET (container))
  Aborted (core dumped)
  ```
- If I take the top-most widget and instead call `reparent()` and pass the `Gtk::Notebook` as the new parent then the new tab does show up with all the widgets correctly arranged, but then I can't control the tab's title.

There must be a 'correct' way to do this, I just can't figure out what it is!

Comment: Maybe create multiple Builder objects and load the XML file into each of them? This will create multiple copies of the widgets.

Comment: @cdhowie: I've updated the question in response, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to help from the `gtkmm` mailing list, I have the solution.

In Glade, I had created a `Gtk::Window` with a single `Gtk::Box` in it, and put all my controls in the `Box`.  This caused problems when trying to add the `Box` as a new tab, because the `Box` already had a parent (the `Gtk::Window`) so it was troublesome trying to make the `Gtk::Notebook` the new parent.

Instead, I found you can right-click on the button for the `Gtk::Box` in Glade, and choose "Add widget as toplevel".  There is then no need for a `Gtk::Window` at all, and as the `Box` has no parent, calling `Gtk::Notebook::append_page()` and passing the `Gtk::Box` works perfectly.  I can then use the variant of `append_page()` that lets me set the tab's title at the same time.

It is still a requirement however to create a new `Gtk::Builder` instance to load the controls for each tab, because each tab needs a new instance of the controls.  If you just keep calling `Gtk::Builder::get_widget()` on the same object, it returns the same instance of the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should first make the layout of your GUI in Glade, complete with Window, Notebook and/or other nested widgets.  If you want different tabs then you also can make them in Glade, but as seperate objects that aren't nested in your toplevel Window.  Save the .xml file and load it into your program.

Declare your widgets as pointers, initialized with the nullptr and use something like this to get access to the widget you made in Glade:

```
 m_refBuilder->get_widget("my_tabbox00", m_pTab00);
```

Now you are able to use (the Glade id) my_tabbox00 as (the C++) pointer m_pTab00.  Just make sure my_tabbox00 has no parent in Glade, it can contain childs.  You also can use get_widget() for the Notebook and the Viewports (even if the widget has a parent).  To append a page you can use:

```
m_pNotebook->append_page(*m_pViewport00, *m_pTab00);
```

Beware that this solution restricts you a little bit because for every tab you have to make a new tab and viewport in Glade.  Maybe a better way would be to try to make a class for the tabs and using multiple objects for this.